# How to understand if an e-mail was actually sent after my app directs me to an e-mail app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a prototype for a "coffee ordering" app. When you submit the order, my app directs the user to an e-mail app with the order details. And when the e-mail is sent, i want to switch to a new activity where it says "Your order was succesfully placed". Now, I've got 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to make the phone send the e-mail automatically, or do the user need to press send themselves?
2. After sending the mail, how do i understand if the e-mail was actually sent?

Here is the code that i am currently using:

```
    public void composeEmail() {

        String[] addresses=new String[1];
        addresses[0]="emailaddress@coffee.com";

        String subject="Coffee Order";

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, orderDetails);

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make the phone send the e-mail automatically

Not using an `Intent` action. You might consider having your app work with a Web service that you create, where that Web service sends the email.

> or do the user need to press send themselves?

Yes, if you are using an `Intent` action.

> After sending the mail, how do i understand if the e-mail was actually sent?

You don't. That information is private to the user and the email client. You might consider having your app work with a Web service that you create, where that Web service sends the email, as then you know when the email is sent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you have any sources where i can learn how to create a web service in java?